# Command Prompt Keeps Closing, C++ and Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-prompt

I have been going through the book "Accelerated C++" and have done the following excercise:

```
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <ios>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using std::cin;         using std::sort;
    using std::cout;        using std::streamsize;
    using std::endl;        using std::string;
    using std::setprecision;
    using std::vector;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "please enter your first name: ";
        string name;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "hello, " << name << "!" < endl;

        cout << "please enter your midterm and final exam grades: ";
        double midterm, final;
        cin >> midterm >> final;

        // read hw grades
        cout << "enter all hw grades followed by end of file: ";
        vector<double> homework;
        double x;

        while(cin >> x)
            homework.push_back(x);

        typedef vector<double>>::size_type vec_sz;
        vec_sz size = homework.size();

        if(size == 0){
            cout << endl << "re-enter grades" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        //compute the median
        sort(homework.begin(),homework.end());
        vec_sz mid = size/2;
        double median;
        median = size % 2 == 0 ? (homework[mid]+homework[mid-1])/2 : homework[mid];

        streamsize prec = cout.precision();
        cout << "final grade is " << setprecision(3) << .2*midterm+.4*final+.4*median
             << setprecision(prec) << endl;

        cin.get();
        cin.get();

        return 0;
    }
```

When the program finishes executing, the command window will close. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and have tried various fixes that include using `cin.get()` and also `cin.ignore()` followed by `cin.get()` and even `cin.get()` repeated twice.The only thing that seems to work is `system("pause")` but I would rather not use this as it seems bad programming practice. I am at a loss and would appreciate any help as I am sure I will run in to this in the future. Thank you guys.

Comment: Try `cin >> x` it works for me.

Comment: Your compiler is optimizing away the unused `cin.get()` calls. @J3soon's solution should avoid that.

Comment: Ctrl-F5 will run the program outside the debugger and will not close the console screen till a key is pushed

Comment: I just tried that again and the same thing, the command prompt just flashes, neither using cin >> var or Ctrl-F5 are leaving the console screen open.

Comment: You instruct the user to put end-of-file indicator on the standard input. Naturally, all subsequent read attempts on that stream fail immediately - it has, after all, reached  end-of-file. You rely on this to get out of `while (cin >> x)` loop.

Comment: @EdCottrell The compiler cannot legally optimize away `cin.get()`. I/O routines have observable side effects; removing such call would violate As-if rule.

Comment: @Ignor Tandetnik I see so when you use end-of-file to exit a loop does this also ignore any use of `cin` later on in the program as well? I used the condition `if (x == 1) break; ` to exit the loop and it seems to be working, I was just wondering if you could explain what happens in more detail when an end-of-file occurs then, thank you!

Comment: Which part of "all subsequent read attempts fail immediately" do you find unclear?

Comment: What you forgot to tell everybody is that you typed Ctrl+Z to stop entering data.   That puts the cin stream into the end-of-file state permanently, any subsequent get() calls return immediately.  It is a clunky way to enter data, do it differently in a way that a normal user can understand.  Like pressing the Enter key without entering a number.  Or specifying the name of a file that contains the data, you'll enjoy that one yourself a lot more.